# How do I do this with the user agent?

Tags: javascript, jquery, user-agent

If the user-agent includes the word "myapp", then alert('hi');

BTW, I am using JQuery.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if (navigator.userAgent.indexOf("myapp") !== -1) {
  alert("hi");
}
```

I recommend you don't do user-agent sniffing.

Comment: +1 For the recommendation against sniffing.  For the rest of the class: Instead of user-agent sniffing, *feature detection* should be used to determine the type of browser that you are dealing with.